# How do I avoid invalid data with multiple programs writing to the same database?

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `MCVESchema`.`MCVETable` (
  `PrimaryKeyColumn` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Increment` INT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PrimaryKeyColumn`));
```

in which multiple programs would be accessing the same row to change the value in the `Increment` column, the following is a concern:

- Instance A of program accesses `Increment` field of row 0 and
  increments value from 0 to 1.
- Instance B of program accesses
  `Increment` field of row 0 and increments value from 0 to 1
- Instance
  A of program writes to the database - `Increment` field of row 0 is
  now 1 ( this is the intended behavior )
- Instance B of program writes back to the
  database - `Increment` field of row 0 is still 1 ( it should be 2 ).

**Should** I be concerned about this? If this is a valid concern, what would I need to do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Yes, if multiple processes / servers / web requests all try to read then update the same row then you have a problem.  Some possible fixes include serializing updates through a single handler, transactions, a lock table to have others back off, wait a random interval, then retry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) which occur due to sequencing errors.

As in you do a *fetch, increment, set* series of operations:

```
A: SELECT -> increment
                             B: SELECT -> increment
A: 0 -> increment
                             B: 0 -> increment
A: increment += 1
                             B: increment += 1
A: UPDATE increment = 1
                             B: UPDATE increment = 1
```

Instead of `increment` ending up at 2, it ends up at 1 because of interleaving.

The better way to do this is as an *atomic operation*, as in one that happens at an instant in time and is not dependent on prior or subsequent steps being applied correctly.

This is typically shown as:

```
UPDATE counter_table SET increment=increment+1 WHERE id=?
```

Each of these statements will run start-to-finish independently in order and there's no chance of a sequencing error. Every time the increment will be adjusted by +1.

This is *especially* important when doing banking-type operations.

In technical terms you may be creating a *counter table*, or a *sequence generator* with a table like this, so investigate what patterns you have for implementing those by searching for examples of those particular things.

Comment: And now I feel really dumb for not thinking of that myself.

Answer (score 0):

While tadman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59886685/10682164) is likely best, if you happen to be in a situation where you can't meet your goal in one atomic SQL operation and still have concerns about race conditions, then one alternative is to use MySQL's locking functionality described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locking-functions.html).